# Stop Hover Effect from Moving Other Elements Down on Page

Tags: css

I'm working on my navigation and I've added an effect that when you hover over a link, a blue border is added to the bottom. It works, but the only problem I'm having is that when you hover over a link, the border pushes all the other elements on the page down 3 pixels (the size of the border).

If anyone could clue me in on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated. Here's the relevent code:

HTML

```
<div id="nav" class="wrapper">
  <div class="site-navigation">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <div class="site-title">Noelle Devoe</div>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.site-navigation {
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.site-navigation a{
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif, Georgia;
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: rgb(82,82,82);
}

.site-navigation a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(4,141,195);
    text-shadow: rgb(200, 200, 200) 1px 1px 0px;
}
```

Comment: The 3px border is causing the issue. Add a 3px transparent border on the non-hover state for a quick fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One easy fix is to add a transparent border when the element isn't being hovered.

Add `border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;` to `.site-navigation a`.

```
.site-navigation a {
    font-family:'Arvo', serif, Georgia;
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: rgb(82, 82, 82);
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems so simple, but I never would have thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding below CSS:

```
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
```

to

```
.site-navigation a
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve the hover problem!

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>



.main{
        height: 205px;
        width: 405px;
    }
    .box{
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        transition: 
        0.3s;
        
    }
    .box:hover{
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        box-shadow: -5px 5px black;
    }
```

Comment: Please try to add an explanation for your answer.